# Importing data into R

Tags: r

So I have a set of data [here](http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgc?hgsid=358528009&g=htcDnaNearGene&i=uc003qec.4&c=chr6&l=133562494&r=133853258&o=knownGene&hgSeq.promoter=on&boolshad.hgSeq.promoter=0&hgSeq.promoterSize=10759&hgSeq.utrExon5=on&boolshad.hgSeq.utrExon5=0&hgSeq.cdsExon=on&boolshad.hgSeq.cdsExon=0&hgSeq.utrExon3=on&boolshad.hgSeq.utrExon3=0&hgSeq.intron=on&boolshad.hgSeq.intron=0&hgSeq.downstream=on&boolshad.hgSeq.downstream=0&hgSeq.downstreamSize=9999&hgSeq.granularity=gene&hgSeq.padding5=0&hgSeq.padding3=0&boolshad.hgSeq.splitCDSUTR=0&hgSeq.casing=upper&boolshad.hgSeq.maskRepeats=0&hgSeq.repMasking=lower&submit=submit) (note: ignore the first line, the data sets from the second line). There are 311,522 characters in total. I wish to import this into R such that each single character is in one cell, so I end up with a 311,522 by 1 column vector. However, when I copied the data into a text file and then imported that into R, each line is recognized as one single "character" and instead I end up with a column vector where each entry is the entire line rather than a single character.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, even if it doesn't work, post the relevant code.

Comment: As suggested above, please post what you have tried.  You might find strsplit("line of text goes here","") useful and ?strsplit.

Comment: I am a beginner at R. All I have done so far is copy the data into a text file, then use R's in built "Import Database" option.

Comment: @MattWeller Thanks, I will have a look at strsplit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `readLines` and `strsplit`. This is pretty straightforward stuff in R:

```
x <- readLines("Your_Actual_URL_Here")
```

Check for any junk:

```
head(x)
# [1] ""                                                                                                     
# [2] "<PRE>"                                                                                                
# [3] ">hg19_knownGene_uc003qec.4 range=chr6:133551736-133863257 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none"
# [4] "AGGGAGAGGAGTATCTTGTCTTGGGGAGGGTGGAGACAGACAACCATTTC"                                                   
# [5] "TGTTTTTGTTATATTGAATTGTACATCTTCCTAGGCATAAATACTCTTCA"                                                   
# [6] "TGATTTCAGGCCAGGTCCAAATGATACCTCCTACATTCCTTCAGCTGGAA"   
tail(x)
# [1] "CTTGCTTTTCACAAAAAGAGATCCAAGAGGAAGAGGTGGAGCAAGCTAGC"
# [2] "AAGAGAGCACCCAAGATGGAAGCTGCAGTCTTTTACCCTAACCTCAGAAG"
# [3] "TGGTGTACCTTTTGCCATATGCCATTTGTCATATAGCTCAAGCATGGTAC"
# [4] "AGTGTGGGAGGGGGCTACATGGGATGTTAATACCAGGATGCAGGGGATCG"
# [5] "CTGGGGCTACTTTGGAGGCTGG"                            
# [6] "</PRE>"
```

So, we want from the fourth line to one less than the length of the vector:

```
y <- unlist(strsplit(x[4:(length(x)-1)], ""), use.names=FALSE)
head(y)
# [1] "A" "G" "G" "G" "A" "G"
tail(y)
# [1] "G" "G" "C" "T" "G" "G"
length(y)
# [1] 311522
```