# Extracting portions of a string of characters

Tags: r

I have a string of characters (311,522 length long). It is in .txt format and all on one line. The data file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/waomrba9259yqc3/eya4_lagan_HM_cp.txt). I tried to import it into R like this:

`eya4_lagan_HM_cp <- read.table("C:/Documents and Settings/SS/Desktop/Sequence Segmentation/eya4_lagan_HM_cp.txt", quote="\"")`

But I get warning messages and it does not import it.

I need to extract portions of this string of characters. That is, I need to extract from 44184 to 44216, meaning the sequence of characters from the 44184th character (inclusive) to the 44216th character (inclusive), then from 151795 to 151844, and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you add info about what error msgs you're getting?

Comment: Why do you suppose read.table is the correct function to use in this case? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068397/import-text-file-as-single-character-string for a similar problem

Comment: Continuing from [my answer at your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21061459/1270695), we ended up with "y". Use `y[44184:44216]` to get the portions of the vector that you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing data into R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061007/importing-data-into-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068397/import-text-file-as-single-character-string for an information on how to read the file into a string, for example you would use:

```
fileName <- "C:/Documents and Settings/SS/Desktop/Sequence Segmentation/eya4_lagan_HM_cp.txt"
theData <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
```

Also see the [readChar](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readChar.html) docs.

See [substr](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substr.html) for information on how to extract substrings.

In your case, you could use for example:

```
mySubstr <- substr(theData, 44184, 44216)
```